# Why does this basic urllib code work, but this basic requests code not?

Tags: python, authentication, urllib, bots, phpbb3

I'm trying to get a bot to log into a phpbb3 forum, which I can do in `urllib`. However, because it requires session IDs etc., it does not stay logged in when you change page (I think this is the problem). So I'm trying to use `requests`, but I cannot even get `requests` to log in, even though its easy to log in with `urllib`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib
import http.cookiejar
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

username = ''
password = ''

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]

auth_url = "http://www.mingeford365.co.uk/forum/ucp.php?mode=login"
payload  = {'username' : username, 'password' : password, 
            "autologin" : "on", 'login' : 'Login'}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
binary_data = data.encode('UTF-8')

req = urllib.request.Request(auth_url,binary_data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
contents = resp.read().decode('UTF-8')

if username in contents:
   print('logged in.')
```

The above code works. The below requests code does not work

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.mingeford365.co.uk/forum/ucp.php?mode=login'

logininfo = {'username': '',
             'password': '',
             'autologin' : "on", 
             'login' : 'Login'}

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (x11; Ubuntu; Linux x86; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0'}
           #'Accept': 'text/html, application/xhtml+xhtml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           #'Accept-Language': 'en-gb,en;q=0.5', 
           #'Accept-Encoding':  'gzip, deflate',                                   
           #'referer': 'http://www.mingeford365.co.uk/forum/index.php',
           #'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
           #'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

session = requests.Session()
get_session_id = session.get("http://www.mingeford365.co.uk/forum",headers=headers)
print(get_session_id.status_code)

response = session.post(url,params=logininfo,headers=headers) #cookies=get_session_id.cookies
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

print(soup.get_text())
```

Comment: Are you sure you that is the right way to pass the logininfo

Comment: Could you provide a more precise problem statement than *"does not work"*?

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your POST body parameters in your URL. Use `data`, not `params`:

```
response = session.post(url, data=logininfo, headers=headers)
```